# Strange edges on my object

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to blender, and following along with an anvil tutorial. Everything was going fine, but some edges of my geometry look weird.

[image]

Any idea on how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Wierd in what way? - If you're talking about the visible edges on the surface you can right-click in the window and choose 'Shade Smooth from the popup menu.

Comment: @Gorgious Being the troglodyte that I am, I must have deleted my duplicate vertices, done something wrong, undo too much, and then forgot to re-delete duplicate vertices. Thank you, and sorry for wasting people's time.

Comment: Don't worry about it. As you can see many many people have had the exact same problem. :) Happy blending